# How can I prevent the user from clicking a button too fast, in order to prevent an extra ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Imagine a button for liking or voting a page. I need this button to send Ajax request to record user's likes.

The people who click the button very fast many times, cause a number of Ajax request.
How can I fix that?
When people click the button(`span`), 
I need to prevent it from sending the Ajax request again until the previous Ajax request is done

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="send_ajax(this)">send_ajax</span>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function send_ajax(node){
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {},
            success:function() {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
var processing = false; 
function send_ajax(node){
  if(!processing){
    processing = true;
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(){
              processing = false;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First you have to unbind click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('span').click(function(){
        $('span').unbind('click');  // unbind click
        //ajax request
    })
</script>
```

Then bind it again in `complete` event that has `$.ajax` method:

```
complete: function() {
    $('span').bind('click'); // will fire either on success or error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function called by the click you can unbind the click-eventhandler, if you add `$(this).unbind('click');`
You would need to change your function this way:

```
function send_ajax(node){
  $(this).unbind('click');
  $.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{},
    success:function(){
    }
  });
}
```

If you need to re-enable it after success, add the click-event within the success-function again. If you in any way validate your data, be sure to return status-information within the .php file, to know that you need to add the event again on failed validation.

I suggest the use of $(this) over the use $('span'), as $('span') will return multiple objects in case you place further spans in your html markup.

Answer (score 1):

In your handler, simply remove the event listener to ignore future clicks.  You can set a timeout to re-add it, or do so as part of your success callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) { 
    $.fn.oneClickPerTime = function (callback,timeDelay) {
        var __this = this;
        flagOneClick = 1;
        return this.each(function () {
            $(__this).click(function() {
                if (flagOneClick==0)
                    return;
                flagOneClick = 0;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    flagOneClick = 1;
                },timeDelay);
                callback(this);
            });
        });
    } 
})(jQuery);

$("#test_click").oneClickPerTime(function(){
    callback_after_click();
},500);
```

You can see my demo here [jsfiddle.net/pvN3u/](http://jsfiddle.net/pvN3u/)